# Pandas Dataframe Add a value to a new Column based on the previous row limited to the maximum value in that column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

It is so hard to learn all the tricks for pandas or working with dataframes.

So I have a df with a certain amount of weeks listed. I wanted to create a metrics table or dataframe that has additional columns added with sequential ascending weeks added only populating the row to the maximum week list in column 'Week'

```
       Week
 0    201152
 1    201201
 2    201202
 3    201203
 4    201204
```

The below df is the result i am trying to get to.

```
       Week  2ndWeek 3rdWeek 4thWeek 5thWeek 
 0    201152  201201  201202  201203  201204
 1    201201  201202  201203  201204
 2    201202  201203  201204  
 3    201203  201204  
 4    201204
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
ts = df.Week
for week in range(len(ts) - 1):
    ts = ts.drop(ts.idxmin())
    ts.index = pd.Index(range(len(ts)))
    ts.name = '%s_Week' % week
    df = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(ts), left_index=True,right_index=True, how='outer')
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey. I get an error messageTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\weektest.py", line 20, in <module>
    ts = ts.drop(max(ts))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 348, in drop
    new_axis = axis.drop(labels)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 1215, in drop
    raise ValueError('labels %s not contained in axis' % labels[mask])
ValueError: labels [ 201204.] not contained in axis   Is it because my Week column is actually digits not a real week date.

Comment: Oh, yes. ts = ts.drop(min(ts)) works only if index is the same as .Week column. Change it to ts=ts.drop(ts.idxmin())

Comment: Also if you need triangle matrix in result, reindex ts on each iteration

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, you could use `shift` and a loop.  There are some index tricks you can pull but it's unlikely this is a bottleneck, so we might as well be simple.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Week": [201152, 201201, 201202, 201203, 201204]})
>>> df
     Week
0  201152
1  201201
2  201202
3  201203
4  201204

[5 rows x 1 columns]
>>> for n in range(2, len(df)+1):
...     df["{}_Week".format(n)] = df["Week"].shift(-(n-1))
...     
>>> df
     Week  2_Week  3_Week  4_Week  5_Week
0  201152  201201  201202  201203  201204
1  201201  201202  201203  201204     NaN
2  201202  201203  201204     NaN     NaN
3  201203  201204     NaN     NaN     NaN
4  201204     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN

[5 rows x 5 columns]
```

If you really want `''` instead of `NaN`, you could add `.fillna('')`, but even though they're not as nice to look at, arithmetic will work much better with `NaN`s, as they're interpreted as missing values by many of the routines.

Comment: Thanks that also works great. I guess I need some more practice on for statements and will look into some more examples with the .shift.